# How to deviate a git branch from a tag?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, bitbucket-server

I'd like to transform every commits after a Git tag into a branch, so to start over the master from this tag and later do a pull request from the branch.

I'd like to start over from the tag and release small chances until the current changes are stabilized.
Is this some kind of rebase command that would do the trick?
Any concrete example would be appreciated

I'd be able to checkout from the tag, and maybe branch from it, but it is the contrary that would really make sense: we should have branched from the master instead of having commited in it.

Thx

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want but doesn't `git checkout my_tag` and `git checkout -b my_new_branch` do what you need?

Comment: would this transfer the commits that occured after my tag into the new branch ?

Comment: I think that maybe the process would involve a kind of detachment; but that's far beyond my regular usage

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you have the following situation:

1. One of your commits is tagged with `mytag`.
2. You have several commits in `master` after `mytag`. All these commits have been pushed to remote.

If I understood you correctly you want several things:

1. You don't want to see commits after `mytag` both in `master` (i.e. your local machine) and `origin/master` (i.e. your remote repository).
2. You want to preserve all commits after `mytag` in separate branch (i.e. `newbranch`).

If I've correctly described what you want then execute these commands:

```
# Switch to latest commit in master:
$git checkout master
# Create new branch:
$git checkout -b newbranch
# Switch back to master:
$git checkout master
# Reset master to "mytag":
$git reset --hard mytag
# Apply changes in master to origin/master:
$git push -f
```

Please note that last command (`git push`) is executed with "force" option (`-f`). This option allows to delete commits in the remote. I highly recommend you to read git documentation about this option.

**CAUTION:** `git push` with "force" option should be applied **only if you are single developer in your project**. If there are several contributors in your project I **strongly discourage** you from applying `git push -f` because it may mess up commit history in local repositories of your coworkers. If there are several contributors then leaving things as they are now is probably the best solution.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear that the commits have been pushed already.

Comment: Removing commits in remote is possible but requires extra work. But i should warn you: although it is possible to delete commits you have pushed to remote it is strongly not recommended. Your coworkers probably pulled commits to master and if these commits will be deleted it may mess up their commit history.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your highlights. Turns out that i've been the only commiter in this case. i'll finally forget the idea and keep in mind branching practices for next time, i guess

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out. I think the edited answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch from the specified tag as follows.

```
git branch new_branch tag_name
```

The `git log` will appear as follows.

```
commit 5ad3849a9de65d9180c1242c7148cc10148xxxxx (HEAD -> feat)
commit ae4b6bb01a74d0f2d8a7c53fe9781186bb2xxxxx (tag: v1, new_branch)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create branches for all tags, for example from `v1.0` to `branch_v1.0`,

```
git push . refs/tags/*:refs/heads/branch_*
```

or

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" | while read tag;do
    git branch branch_$tag;
done
```